# redirect the root of a domain, while leaving the www version unredirected

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have some bad links pointing at `abc.com`. Wordpress automatically redirects `abc.com` to `www.abc.com`.

I need to redirect `abc.com` to a holding page... let's say `www.abc.com/holding.html`.

What is the best way to do this?

I've tried a bunch of things but none of them work :(

Comment: Is it WordPress that's redirecting abc.com to www.abc.com, or is it your hosting provider?

Comment: Hi Pat, i believe WP automatically redirects from one to the other since v2.4

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting on a LAMP environment. You can put this redirect in .htaccess file. RedirectRule must be placed before the WordPress generate rules. So that, your rule get executed before WordPress take it through. RewriteRule will look something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / # if WP installed in a folder use /folder_name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /holding.html [L] # to redirect all 404 pages
RewriteRule bad_link\.html /holding.html [L] # to redirect selected 404 page
</IfModule>
```

Note: Make sure it is placed before the WordPress generate Rewrites. Otherwise, it wont be work

**Edit:** To redirect domain.com to domain.com/holding.html replace 7th line with following

```
RewriteRule ^$ /holding.html [L] # to domain.com to holding.html page
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Not sure what is meant by 'before the wordpress generate rewrites exactly... i inputted it above what i think you meant, but it didnt work.  Here's a copy of my very short .htaccess file. I added your code in lines 8-17. What do you think? Thanks!!

Comment: couldnt paste it here so here is a link to see it: http://pastebin.com/YKD4KAnk

Comment: Move it to top of the file. Do you see an internal server error or what? have you properly changed the domain name? Moreover, add "RewriteBase" too.

Comment: No error, it just doesnt redirect from http://domain.com to http://domain.com/holding.html. I added 'RewriteBase /' and also tried deleting line 18 onwards - so my .htaccess file only contains what you advised. What do you mean by 'bad_link'?

Comment: Updated the answer for "domain.com" specific redirect. Please check.

Comment: Thanks. Still no joy. I shall clarify: I need the individual page 'http://domain.com' to go to http://domain.com/holding.html.  http://www.domain.com should remain unaffected.  Does this change your interpretation? Thank you M-R!

Comment: yes, it definitely does. The rule I just provided is supposed to redirect 'domain.com' to 'www.domain.com/holding.html' (note the www). I am assuming domain.com to www.domain.com redirect is implicitly done by the WordPress. If you can share 5-8 list of existing+required url redirection that may clear up the scenario.

Comment: How confusing - this text box deletes the http i put in front of domain names! To put it differently again, i just need one page to redirect - domain.com(no www.) and for it to go somewhere else such as /holding.html.  www.domain.com should remain unaffected. You are right - Wordpress automatically redirects domain.com to www.domain.com, which makes this redirect problematic... this is the only redirect i want to change, i have setup no other redirects. Thank you for all your time on this M-R, if you are sick of replying i understand!